# Can Special Attacks Cross-Up?

Tags: fight-the-fighting-game-rpg

**Can Special Attacks be used to perform a Cross-Up?**

The rules in the combat section state (emphasis mine):

> If a combatant can jump forward 2 Ranges to attack with a **Basic
>   Move** and land exactly at Range 0, and then chooses to spend an
>   additional 1 FS, the combatant can do a Cross-Up Attack.

A Basic Move is, by definition, not a Special Move, and thus cannot have Elements or Liabilities associated with it.

However, there is a Liability named ***Cross-Up Liability*** that can be added to Special Moves that reads (emphasis mine):

> This move can **only be used** if it is used in **a Cross-Up situation.** 
>   Otherwise, it automatically misses.

Also by definition, a Liability can only be added to Special Moves, and not to Basic Moves.

How does this interact?  It appears that it is possible to make a Special Move that can **only be used as a Cross-Up,** but it also appears that **Special Moves cannot be used to Cross-Up at all.**

Does the Liability also grant the ability to Cross-Up? (Generally, Liabilities are strictly negative effects, and such a beneficial effect would require an Element.) Does the word "situation" mean that it can be used in a similar scenario, but does not gain the usual benefits of being a Cross-Up? Is there another way to make Special Moves able to Cross-Up?  Are one of the rules incorrect?

Comment: What is the logical chain that leads you up to the "Special Moves cannot be used to Cross-Up at all" ? I am not seeing it in the rules you provide here. The first statement I would parse as "If you are able to do A but choose to spend additional resources, you can instead do B". No limitations on B here specifically.

Comment: @Nox I agree that the wording could be interpreted that way, but the section that is from is the *only* section that discusses Cross-Up Attacks (in its own section labeled as such).  I see it as saying "The way - and the only way - to do B is to do A."  I'm taking this from the context that there is no other explanation of what a Cross-Up Attack is in the book, AFAIK.

Comment: I sent the message to one of the game creators (I know him via a superhero RPG forum) and hopefully he'll stop by for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I concede that the rule on p. 220 could be explained better.  A "Cross-Up Situation" is one in which one moves 2 Ranges and stops at Range 0 exactly and then spends 1 FS.  Normally, this cannot be done with a Special Move *unless* it is a move with the Cross-Up Liability.  Essentially, the Limitation provides one very specific situation in which it can be used.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.